# Trip Route total Distance calculation from Here map PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener two geo points

Tags: android, here-api

hello here map followers I am facing problem with total trip distance completed number. I am calculating the start station geo points with current location geo points (till end station)using Haversine formula. As per the formula calculation it's total distance is fine but if I put the same start station and end station geo points in google map to check the total distance I am wondered both are different. I checked with vehicle ride the result is same, missing in the total distance traveled vehicle km/h VS Haversine formula is their solution in here map for this to get the traveled total distance. Answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am really not sure if I got the question right (and I'll adapt the answer if I am wrong).

In HERE Maps, you can get the elapsed distance in navigation mode via

```
NavigationManager.getInstance().getElapsedDistance()
```

This is the elapsed time on the routed distance. 
All distances in Routing and Navigation are routed distances.
When using haversine you calculate the distances air-line.